# Can't call fetch directly in Backbone model listenTo

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to have a model listen to a collection and fetch itself when the collection changes:

```
class Team extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/team',

  initialize: function(attributes, options) {

    this.listenTo(members, 'change', this.fetch)
```

The fetch does seem to trigger, but the url is all messed up, and to get it to work I have to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
this.listenTo(members, 'change', function() {this.fetch();})
```

Interestingly when I add a "test" function to the model and put this.fetch() inside it, it works:

```
this.listenTo(members, 'change', this.test)

test: function() {
     this.fetch();
}
```

Why can't I just do `this.fetch` inside the `listenTo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler for each type of event is passed a certain set of arguments. The [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) has this to say about a `"change"` event:

> - **"change" (model, options)** — when a model's attributes have changed.

So if you say this:

```
this.listenTo(members, 'change', this.fetch)
```

then `fetch` will be called like this:

```
fetch(the_model_that_changed, some_options_object)
```

But [`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) expects to be called with just an `options` object. The result is that `fetch` will be looking for `options` in a model instance and the result is confusion.